# C++ search "regex operators" with regex

Tags: c++, regex

Im using regex in C++ and want regex_search * and + symbols, but it wont work, cause they are regex symbols.
(using namespace std)

```
string s = "15 * 12";
regex rx("*");
bool flag = regex_search(s, rx);
```

and

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::regex_error: One of *?+{ was not preceded by a valid regular expression.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: escape them with a `\\`

Comment: Of course, doing this search with a regular expression is overkill.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes it is in that example, but of course, its only an example ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters using '\'. If you specify that in a c++ string constant you need to add two '\' something like "\*".